# How do I dispatch an action from a Container method in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux and I have this question that I can't solve by myself.

I created a TODO list app and now I need to add a new task to the list. The user writes something in a text input and when he clicks the button the new task must be appended to the list.

I already get a 'ADD TASK' action. But I don't know how to call it from inside a component method. So I added an event listener to the button, but when I click it what should I do next?

```
class List extends React.Component{
  addTask(e){
    var title = $('[name=title]');
    title.val('');
    //what should I do?
  }

  render(){
    const mappedTasks = this.props.tasks.map(function(task){
      return (
        <li key={task.title}>{task.title}</li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {mappedTasks}
        </ul>
        <input name='title' />
        <button onClick={this.addTask}>Adicionar</button>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

const mapStateToProps = function(state,ownProps){
  return {
    message: 'Hello World!',
    tasks: state.tasks
  }
}



const ListComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(List);
```

In this example I want to dispatch something from the addTask method.
So what is the proper way of dispatching from a Component method on Redux?

**@edit** this did the trick:
In render function

```
<button onClick={this.addTask.bind(this)}>Adicionar</button>
```

So as Brandon said I could use in the method

```
this.props.dispatch({type:'ADD_TASK', payload: {title: title.value}});
```

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of possible solutions, and which one is more appropriate might depend on your particular use case. There are a few questions that might help:

1. Is this `List` component `connect`-ed to the redux store (using the `connect()` decorator from the `react-redux` package? If so, you
   should be able to dispatch an action as simply as this:
   `this.props.dispatch(someActionCreator())`.
2. Are you open to `connect`-ing this component to the store? If so, decorate the `List` component like so: `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(List)`. Then you'll have access to `dispatch()` on props in the `List` component and can proceed just as in question 1.
3. Does the `List` component have an ancestor with access to the `dispatch()` function. If so, you can create an action dispatching function at that level and pass it down as a prop until you reach the `List` component, where you can call that function.

As I said, your particular use case will determine the suitability of each approach. If you have any more questions, I'm happy to help, so let me know.

Comment: I updated my question with my `connect` function. `this` in the component method is null.

the `mapStateToProps` works well and the re-render is happening

Answer (score 0):

Can use something like this.

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import * as TodoActionCreators from './TodoActionCreators'
console.log(TodoActionCreators)
// {
//   addTodo: Function,
//   removeTodo: Function
// }

class TodoListContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
   // Injected by react-redux:
   let { dispatch } = this.props

   // Note: this won't work:
   // TodoActionCreators.addTodo('Use Redux')

  // You're just calling a function that creates an action.
  // You must dispatch the action, too!

  // This will work:
   let action = TodoActionCreators.addTodo('Use Redux')
   dispatch(action)
}

render() {
// Injected by react-redux:
   let { todos, dispatch } = this.props

// Here's a good use case for bindActionCreators:
// You want a child component to be completely unaware of Redux.

let boundActionCreators = bindActionCreators(TodoActionCreators, dispatch)
console.log(boundActionCreators)
// {
//   addTodo: Function,
//   removeTodo: Function
// }

return (
  <TodoList todos={todos}
            {...boundActionCreators} />
)

// An alternative to bindActionCreators is to pass
// just the dispatch function down, but then your child component
// needs to import action creators and know about them.

// return <TodoList todos={todos} dispatch={dispatch} />
}
}

export default connect(
  state => ({ todos: state.todos })
)(TodoListContainer)
```

Answer (score 0):

One most common way to dispatch an action in component is to dispose the action to props using mapDispatchToProps.  Then you can dispatch an action from props.

```
componentWillMount() {   
   this.props.actions.loadPropImages();
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(imageActions, dispatch) 
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditorPage);
```